# Exclude certain records from running total (SQL) Snowflake

Tags: sql, sum, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, recursive-query

I have table with charges and budget. Different records could have different budget
I I want NOT to increase running sum if it is greater than budget in the record.

Like whenever is running sum is greater than budget in the partition it stops increasing and then increases again when budget is greater.

Is it possible?

```
create table spend 
(id number,
cents number,
budget number);

insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(1,25,50);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(2,25,50);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(3,25,50);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(4,25,50);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(5,25,100);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(6,25,100);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(7,25,100);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(8,25,200);
insert into spend(id,cents,budget) values(9,25,200);
```

That’s what I got

```
vadimzilberleyb#TRANSFORM_WH@INSTADATA.DWH>select s.*, sum(cents) over(order by id)  from spend s;
+----+-------+--------+------------------------------+                          
| ID | CENTS | BUDGET | SUM(CENTS) OVER(ORDER BY ID) |
|----+-------+--------+------------------------------|
|  1 |    25 |     50 |                           25 |
|  2 |    25 |     50 |                           50 |
|  3 |    25 |     50 |                           75 |
|  4 |    25 |     50 |                          100 |
|  5 |    25 |    100 |                          125 |
|  6 |    25 |    100 |                          150 |
|  7 |    25 |    100 |                          175 |
|  8 |    25 |    200 |                          200 |
|  9 |    25 |    200 |                          225 |
+----+-------+--------+------------------------------+
```

And here is what I want :)

```
id       cents  budget   cumul in run    cumulative desirable in run

1          25         50          25                 25
2.        25          50          50                 50
3          25         50          75                 50
4          25         50          100               50
5          25         100         125               75
6          25         100         150               100
7          25         100         175               100
8          25         200         200               125
9          25         200         225               150
```

Comment: Do you know if the budget will always be hit?

Comment: Not always. At least the biggest one  might not

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done with solely window functions. You need some kind of iterative process to decide step by step if the current `cents` should be added to the cumulative `sum`. In SQL, this is usually implemented with a recursive query:

```
with 
    data as (
        select id, cents, budget, row_number() over(order by id) rn
        from spend
    ),
    rec as (
        select d.*, cents cumul from data d where rn = 1
        union all
        select 
            d.*, 
            case when r.cumul + d.cents > d.budget 
                then r.cumul 
                else r.cumul + d.cents 
            end
        from rec r
        inner join data d on d.rn = r.rn + 1
    )
select * from rec
```

If `id` always starts at `1` and increment with no gaps, then you don't need the first cte:

```
with rec as (
    select s.*, cents cumul from spend s where id = 1
    union all
    select 
        s.*, 
        case when r.cumul + s.cents > s.budget 
            then r.cumul 
            else r.cumul + s.cents 
        end
    from rec r
    inner join spend s on s.id = r.id + 1
)
select * from rec
```

[Here is demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b3c27dd40f5c270ce3e04e63fd25f01) - this is SQL Server (since there is no snowflake fiddle in the wild), but the syntax should work equally well on snowlake:

```
id | cents | budget | rn | cumul
-: | ----: | -----: | -: | ----:
 1 |    25 |     50 |  1 |    25
 2 |    25 |     50 |  2 |    50
 3 |    25 |     50 |  3 |    50
 4 |    25 |     50 |  4 |    50
 5 |    25 |    100 |  5 |    75
 6 |    25 |    100 |  6 |   100
 7 |    25 |    100 |  7 |   100
 8 |    25 |    200 |  8 |   125
 9 |    25 |    200 |  9 |   150
```